# Socket IO limits emits?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, socket.io

So I'm using socket.io in react native and I had a functioning app where the user can create a room then leave it

**Client**

- AddRoom - emit
- LeaveRoom - emit
- AddRoomReturn - on
- LeaveRoomReturn - on

```js
export const GroupContext = createContext<GroupService>(null);

export const GroupProvider = (props: any): any => { 
    const endpoint = "http://192.168.0.13:3000";
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState<SocketIOClient.Socket>(socketIO(endpoint, {transports: ["websocket"], jsonp: false}));
    const [group, setGroup] = useState<Group>(null);
    const [isInGroup, setIsInGroup] = useState<Boolean>(false);

    socket.on("connect", () => {
        console.log("connected");
    });
    socket.on("addGroupReturn", (data) => {
        console.log(data)
        if (data.errorCode === 0) {
            let group:Group = JSON.parse(data.group);
            setGroup(group);
            setIsInGroup(true);
            console.log("joined group: " + group.GroupId);
        }
        else if (data.errorCode === 1) {
            console.log("You are already in a group");
        }

    });
    socket.on("joinGroupReturn", (data) => {
        console.log(data)
        if (data.errorCode === 0) {
            let group:Group = JSON.parse(data.group);
            setGroup(group);
            setIsInGroup(true);
            console.log("joined group: " + group.GroupId);
        }
        else if (data.errorCode === 1) {
            console.log("You are already in a group");
        }
        else if (data.errorCode === 2) {
            console.log("Group doesn't exist!");
        }
    });

    socket.on("leaveGroupReturn", () => {
        console.log("Left the group");
        setIsInGroup(false);
        setGroup(null);
    })
    const AddGroup = (nickName: string) => {
        socket.emit("addGroup", nickName);
    }
    const JoinGroup = (nickName: string) => {
        console.log("This gets called");
        socket.emit("test"); //This doesn't
    }
    const LeaveGroup = () => {
        socket.emit("leaveGroup");
    }
    return <GroupContext.Provider value={{...group, isInGroup, AddGroup, JoinGroup, LeaveGroup, GetMembers, GetCurrentGroupId}} {...props} />;
}
export const useGroupService = (): GroupService => {
    const context = useContext<GroupService>(GroupContext); 
    if (typeof context === 'undefined') {
        throw new Error('GroupContext must be used within a GroupProvider');
    }
    return context;
}
```

**Server**

- AddRoom - on
- LeaveRoom - on
- AddRoomReturn - emit
- LeaveRoomReturn - emit

```js
const PORT: number = parseInt(process.env.PORT as string, 10);
const app = express();
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

let groups: Group[] = [];

const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
const io = socketIo(server, {
  transports: ["websocket"]
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {

  console.log("A client connected...")
  socket.emit("connect");
  socket.on("addGroup", (nickName) => {
    if (isSocketIdInGroup(socket.id)) {
      socket.emit("addGroupReturn", { errorCode: 1 });
    } else {
      let id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
      if (nickName === "") nickName = "Anonymous";
      let member: Member = {
        nickName: nickName + " (Leader)",
        socketId: socket.id,
      };
      let group: Group = { GroupId: id, Members: [member] };
      groups.push(group);
      socket.emit("addGroupReturn", {
        errorCode: 0,
        group: JSON.stringify(group),
      });
      console.log(groups);
    }  
  });
  
  socket.on("test", () => {
    console.log("HI"); //This doesn't call
  });
  
  socket.on("leaveGroup", () => {
    leaveGroup(socket);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected");
    leaveGroup(socket);
  });
  
});
```

This works perfectly...*However* when I try adding a new emit on the client the new websocket just doesn't work. Also, when I run it in chrome and look under the "network" tab in developer tools the above examples show up, however, the below does not.

I even tried making it as simple as possible:

Client

```js
console.log("This log works");
socket.emit("test");
```

Server

```js
socket.on("test", () => {
  console.log("This log DOESN'T Work");
});
```

I'm literally at a loss. I don't know why the others work but this doesn't...It's literally a copy paste of the ones that work. 
I really appreciate any help.

Comment: We're going to need a "working" example if you're asking for troubleshooting help.

Comment: Did you setup the socket before emitting? If so, please mention socket establishment code as well.

Comment: Ok, I updated it. I omitted some of the functions that just do array manipulation such as "isSocketIdInGroup" which just has 2 for loops